# sorting with bash, how to sort output from awk

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

Here we have file like a log, each process has acknowledgement
i have to get all history about creating an apple. so i need to find all strings were apple is created, after that i should find all created status for apples as pattern we use number of process, and result should be sorted by time stack.log is below

```
03:01:29.312    5 process   create apple
05:22:42.211    1 process   create banana
05:22:42.302    1 process   created
06:09:32.083    12 process  create apple
05:12:32.759    5 process   created
07:21:45.112    11 process  create orange
06:09:35.083    12 process  created
03:01:25.714    21 process  create apple
05:12:32.308    7 process   create grape
05:12:32.309    7 process   created
05:12:32.300    21 process  created
07:25:41.000    11 process  created
```

here is sample output for this task

```
03:01:25.714    21 process  create apple
03:01:29.312    5 process   create apple
05:12:32.300    21 process  created
05:12:32.759    5 process   created
06:09:32.083    12 process  create apple
06:09:35.083    12 process  created
```

here is a code i've tried

```
a=($(awk '$5 == "apple" { print $2 }' stack.log))
for i in "${a[@]}"
do
    awk -v search="$i" '$0 ~ search { print $1 }' stack.log
done
```

Comment: @Thor exactly, i need two loops, because i don't know when status will be known, because status don't mention apples in it.  i need creation and created status for apples, but created status i can find only with process number. Process number for apples are different from time to time, so i need to find all process numbers, after all time for them. moreover, i can't do this in opposite way: search and sort processes and after that select only apples, because file is very big, and there are a lot of other items

Comment: Okay. How about sorting the source file before you parse it?  That would make the task simpler and doable in one parse

Comment: @Thor i thought that sorting few fields is easier than sort all log file with a big amount of other data. Even it will be sorted we anyway need twice parsing, because for first time we dont have enough information  what we are looking for. Am i wrong? with the first loop we will got `03:01:25.714    21 process  create apple`
`03:01:29.312    5 process   create apple`
`06:09:32.083    12 process  create apple`  but no information about created status? sorry for dumb question

Comment: Assuming the "created" lines always come after the "create apple" lines it is also doable in one-parse  without sorting. Just remember the process id number until the "created" line comes along

Comment: @Thor as far as i understand you it looks like every string we compare with apple or with the stored number of process? if stored process is founded we have to delete it? but what we will do if we will store 10 process numbers to check? we each string will compare with 10 values? For example something happened and for a long time we have no confirmation that apples are created, but we continue to create them :) so we will have 10 messages with create apple, and no one with created, so on this stage we will have to store 10 processes and every string should be compared with every of this proces

Comment: With a hash or associative array, see my answer below

Comment: @Thor thank you for answer, can i ask you to explain how its work?

Comment: I have added an explanation, let me know if something is unclear

Comment: @Thor everything is clear even for me :)) thank you for help, i really appreciate it!! i hope one day i also will give advice for newbies :)!!

Comment: @Thor sorry again, i've got one more question/

Comment: @Thor sorry again, i've got one more question.:`awk '/create apple/ { h[$2]; print; next } $2 in h { print; delete h[$2] }'` is it possible to pickup 2fields into hash, and before printing it check this additional field to the rule? like this '/create apple/ { h[$2,$1] and if $1 = "03:01:25.714" do something. ? one more time sorry for distourbing ..i tried several times but no good result:( also read about 2 dimensional arrays, so believe that is possible:)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You should probably post this as a new question adhering to the [MCVE guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, if you are satisfied with my solution you should remember to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it, so people know the question has a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Thor thank you one more time for help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "created" lines always come after the "create apple" lines it is doable in one-parse, e.g.:

```
awk '/create apple/ { h[$2]; print; next } $2 in h { print; delete h[$2] }'
```

Sort the output:

```
awk ... | sort
```

Output:

```
03:01:25.714    21 process  create apple
03:01:29.312    5 process   create apple
05:12:32.300    21 process  created
05:12:32.759    5 process   created
06:09:32.083    12 process  create apple
06:09:35.083    12 process  created
```

#### Explanation

The awk script consists of two blocks:

```awk
/create apple/ {    # Only run on lines containing the pattern
  h[$2]             # Save process id in hash
  print             # Print the line
  next              # Skip to next line
}
```

and

```awk
$2 in h {           # If this process id was seen before
  print             # Print the line
  delete h[$2]      # and remove the id from the hash
}
```

The idea is to only remember process ids until the matching id is found. This should only happen if a previous `create apple` line is present.

Note that if your data is inconsistent, you need a lot more error checking.